# How do I subclass a UITableView that's in a UISearchDisplayController that I've added via Interface Builder?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad

How do I subclass the UITableView that's in the UISearchDisplayController that I've added via Interface Builder? Obviously I have no way to connect an IBOutlet to it in IB.

Better yet, how do I access the UITableView AT ALL outside of its delegate methods?

The class this is all in is a UIViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UISearchDisplayController has a readonly "searchResultsTableView" property. If the question is how to subclass it - I guess you would have to subclass the UISearchDisplayController and create your own searchResultsTableView, but if you only need to access it there shouldn't be a problem accessing the property directly.